Question about arabtext
I have a problem with following code of arabtext. In fact, the title of the chapter is not written on the top of each page.
Thank you in advance for the help.
\documentclass[12pt,leqno,oneside,headsepline,footsepline]{book} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
 \usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} 
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 
 
 
 \usepackage{lmodern}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
 \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
 \pagestyle{empty}
 
 \newcommand{\espaceh}{39mm}
 \newcommand{\espacev}{23mm}
 
 \newcommand{\taille}{-15mm}
 \newcommand{\lisse}{\espaceh/2}
 \newcommand{\continu}{\lisse + \espaceh - 5}
 \newcommand{\mesurable}{\continu + \espaceh + 30}
 \newcommand{\mesure}{\mesurable + \espaceh + 15}
 \newcommand{\ordrefini}{\mesure + \espaceh - 10}
 \newcommand{\distribution}{\ordrefini + \espaceh - 10}
 
 \newcommand{\regularite}{-10mm}
 \newcommand{\compact}{\espacev/2}
 \newcommand{\decroitvite}{\compact + \espacev}
 \newcommand{\integrable}{\decroitvite + \espacev + 2}
 \newcommand{\borne}{\integrable + \espacev + 15}
 \newcommand{\tempere}{\borne + \espacev}
 \newcommand{\locmtfini}{\tempere + \espacev + 10}
 
 \renewcommand{\c}{\centering}
 \newcommand{\ex}{ex\,:\;}
 \newcommand{\vertex}{\node[draw, rectangle, rounded corners=3pt]}
 \newcommand{\subvertex}{\node[draw, rectangle, rounded corners=3pt, dashed]}
 \newcommand{\fleche}{\draw[decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=1.5]{>}}}, postaction={decorate}, shorten >=0.4pt]}
 \newcommand{\flechesuperieure}[1]{%
    \draw[line width=5pt, white, shorten <=5pt, shorten >=5pt] #1
    \draw[decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=1.5]{>}}}, postaction={decorate}, shorten >=0.4pt] #1}
 
 
 
 \mdfsetup{%
    middlelinecolor=red,
    middlelinewidth=2pt,
    backgroundcolor=red!10,
    roundcorner=10pt}
 %\mdfdefinestyle{exampledefault}{backgroundcolor=red!20}
%\usepackage{mathabx}
%%%
\textwidth=16truecm%13truecm
\textheight=23truecm
\voffset=-2truecm
\hoffset=-1.5truecm%-0.5truecm
%%% 
\usepackage[pdfauthor={كلمة},
pdftitle={مدخل }]{hyperref}

%\hypersetup{% bookmarks=true,
%   unicode=true,
%   colorlinks=true,
%   citecolor=green, %black,
%   filecolor=black,
%   linkcolor=blue, 
%   urlcolor=cyan, 
%}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsmath} وجود هذه الرزمة يجل طبع رقم المعادات بقوسين مقلوبين.
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%%%
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[markcase=noupper,% remove the uppercasing
automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ofoot*{ الأستاذة   
    
\ifoot*{الكلمة} 
    
\cfoot*{}
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\ihead{\leftmark}
%%%
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt[Script=Arabic,Scale=.75]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontrm[Script=Arabic,Scale=.75]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=1]{DejaVu Sans Mono}%Ubuntu,
%\newfontfamily\englishfontrm[Scale=1]{Ubuntu}%,DejaVu Sans Mono
\usepackage{makeidx}
%\usepackage[active]{srcltx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{arabtex}
\setarab \novocalize \ligsfalse 
%%% 13/08/20
\newtheorem{qad}{\textarabic{قضية}}[chapter]
\newtheorem{mob}{\textarabic{مبرهنة}}[chapter]
\newtheorem{t`}{\textarabic{تعريف}}[chapter]%t`ryf
\newtheorem{n.z}{\textarabic{نظرية}}[chapter]
\newtheorem{ml}{\textarabic{ملاحظة}}[chapter]
\newtheorem{tmr}{\textarabic{تمرين}}[chapter]
\newtheorem{htmr}{\textarabic{حل التمرين}}[chapter]
\newtheorem{tw}{\textarabic{توطئة}}[chapter]
\newtheorem{t`-n.z}{\textarabic{تعريف ـ نظرية}}[chapter]
\newtheorem{nt}{\textarabic{نتيجة}}[chapter]
%%%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\timesr}{\fontfamily{artimes}\selectfont}
\let\times\relax
\DeclareMathSymbol{\times}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"02}
\mathchardef\cap="225C
\mathchardef\times="2202
\mathchardef\omega="0121
%\input{latifa}
\newcommand{\dfrac}[2]{\displaystyle{{#1}\over {#2}}}
\newcommand{\binom}[2]{{{#1}\choose{#2}}}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
%\includeonly{dist-preface}







\begin{document}

    
    

\chapter{المعادلات}


\begin{english}
    \begin{arabtext}
        bla
        \end{arabtext}
        \end{english}
        
        
        \newpage
        
\begin{english}
    \begin{arabtext}
        bla
    \end{arabtext}
\end{english}       






\end{document} 


Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe you can  limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at this guide for how to prune your code for this purpose.

Your \ofoot command is missing a closing }. With that added and then running xetex, the header will appear, although it complains that the \end is inside a group (I can't find out what group). But running with luatex, the header disappears. But then it also complains "String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.", so the file is not properly compiled.

I add a closing but there is no header. If i compile with Lualatex, i find error. What we can do to obtaine a file proprely compilerd? Please

I don't think that arabtex is compatible with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.
